# Check if $var = anything in an array?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to be able to test if $post_count is equal to any number in a given array. Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
$posts_even = array(2,4,6,8,10);
$posts_odd = array(1,3,5,7,9);
$posts_ev3 = array(1,4,7,10);
$posts_ev4 = array(1,5,9);
```

--

```
$post_count=1;
$post_count=++; //in wordpress loop so each subsequent post is +1
```

--

```
if ($post_count= //any value in $posts_ev4) :
    echo 'this'
else :
    NULL;
endif;
```

I have been able to make this work using the or operator but I end up with very long blocks of code.....

```
if (($post_count=1) || ($post_count=2)) :
    echo 'this'
else :
    NULL;
endif;
```

I am guessing there is a simpler way to do this but I am new to PHP so I am not sure! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Woah, be careful there, `=` doesn't mean "equal to", it means assignment. You probably want `==` in your `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks..... I completely forgot that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
if (in_array($post_count, $post_ev4)) {}
```

See: [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Answer (score 3):

Use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check if value exists in array.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (in_array($post_count, $posts_ev4)) :
    echo 'this'
else :
    NULL;
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the isset() function in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

Answer (score 1):

There are array functions in php. Ypu can use "is_array" function to check whether its array or not. & to check for a value you can use "in_array" function.

```
if(is_array($array) && in_array($post_count,$array))
{  
   // do operation
}
```